# Simple Vector Component Problem in 2D

Tags: vectors

Please help with vector components! Which of the following is true? 
(Context is displacement of an object)
$$1) \vec A_x+ \vec A_y= \vec A_{total}$$
$$2) \vec A_x^2+\vec A_y^2=\vec A_{total}^2$$
$$3) \lvert \vec A_x \rvert ^2 + \lvert \vec A_y \rvert ^2 = \lvert \vec A_{total} \rvert ^2$$
I think the first (by definition) and third (by Pythagorean Theorem) are true but I don't know about the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so you already seem to know the rules of vector addition and Pythagoras's theorem. You should however note that vector quantities (unless you're talking about the cross product, which you're not) cannot be squared. So you are right in supposing that option 1 and 3 are correct, but option 2 is definitely incorrect. I hope this helped to answer your question.

P.S Try not to ask homeworkish questions or admins might put your question on hold. :-(

Comment: Thank you! That helped very much.